# vba word wdDialogFileSaveAs doesn't save

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I have a bit of word vba code to streamline my workflow. Part of that is safe a template file to a specific file location deep in subfolder structure.

```
Function saveFile(fileType As String)
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim StrPath As String
    Dim instance As WdSaveFormat
    Dim format As String

    'provide a file type
    format = fileType

    'provide default filename
    docname = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).cell(2, 1).Range.Text
    saveName = Left(docname, Len(docname) - 2)

    'provide a path
    projectnumber = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).cell(11, 3).Range.Text
    projectnum = Left(projectnumber, Len(projectnumber) - 2)
    projecttop = Left(projectnumber, Len(projectnumber) - 4)
    pathFull = "H:\Projecten\P0" & projecttop & "00 - P0" & projecttop & "99\P0" & projectnum & "\2 - Bedrijfsbureau\2.Berekeningen\2.2 Berekeningen voorlopig\"

    'provide a revision
    If ActiveDocument.Tables(2).cell(2, 2).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
        MsgBox ("Er is niets ingevult?")
    ElseIf ActiveDocument.Tables(2).cell(3, 2).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
        revLet = ""
    ElseIf ActiveDocument.Tables(2).cell(4, 2).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
        revLet = "_A"
    ElseIf ActiveDocument.Tables(2).cell(5, 2).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
        revLet = "_B"
    ElseIf ActiveDocument.Tables(2).cell(6, 2).Range.Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
        revLet = "_C"
    Else
        revLet = "_D"
    End If

    'concat path
    StrPath = pathFull & saveName & revLet

    With Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
        .Name = StrPath
        .format = format
        If .Display <> 0 Then
            strFileName = .Name
        Else
            strFileName = "User Cancelled"
        End If
    End With
End Function

and calling the funcion

    Private Sub CommandButton19_Click()
    'wdFormatXMLDocument => docx wdFormatDocument => doc wdFormatPDF => pdf
    Call saveFile(wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton20_Click()
    'wdFormatXMLDocument => docx wdFormatDocument => doc wdFormatPDF => pdf
    Call saveFile(wdFormatPDF)
End Sub
```

the pdf one saves the file as expected, but the word one doesn't... I have tried some different option and manually using save as prompt an error... something with compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually surprised saving as PDF works... You use .Display to present the dialog box to the user. Display will NOT EXECUTE the dialog box action chosen by the user: If he clicks Save that command will not be executed. Display only shows the dialog box and the user actions will change the dialog box state. The state can be read after-the-fact and your own code would need to do the saving.

If you want the dialog box to do what the user chooses you need to use the .Show method: If .Show Then...

Comment: Cindy, thanks that work! its is a bit of an odd construct, but I'm getting there.

Comment: Yes, the functionality behind the Word dialogs dates back to the old WordBasic days, some 20 years ago. So they are definitely odd beasts!